# UPD client and server for broadcast messages on a local LAN in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, udp, broadcast

Here are the UDP's broadcast codes adopted from [Foundations of Python Network Programming](https://github.com/brandon-rhodes/fopnp/blob/m/py3/chapter02/udp_broadcast.py)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3 
# UDP client and server for broadcast messages on a local LAN

import argparse, socket

BUFSIZE = 65535

def server(interface, port):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.bind((interface, port))
    print('Listening for datagrams at {}'.format(sock.getsockname()))
    while True:
        data, address = sock.recvfrom(BUFSIZE)
        text = data.decode('ascii')
        print('The client at {} says: {!r}'.format(address, text))

def client(network, port):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
    text = 'Broadcast datagram!'
    sock.sendto(text.encode('ascii'), (network, port))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    choices = {'client': client, 'server': server}
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Send, receive UDP broadcast')
    parser.add_argument('role', choices=choices, help='which role to take')
    parser.add_argument('host', help='interface the server listens at network the client sends to')
    parser.add_argument('-p', metavar='port', type=int, default=1060, help='UDP port (default 1060)')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    function = choices[args.role]
    function(args.host, args.p)
```

I firgued out my laptop's broadcast ip is **192.168.0.255** by running `ifconfig |grep inet`.

```
inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
inet6 fe80::3f:e4b3:b7fb:5de8%en0 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0x4 
inet 192.168.0.27 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.0.255
inet6 fe80::7409:5aff:fe4b:ccf6%awdl0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x8 
inet6 fe80::5f53:baa3:9e02:e706%utun0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0xa
```

Then I created two servers in two different terminals,  one was `python3 udp_broadcast.py server localhost` , the other was `python3 udp_broadcast.py server 192.168.0.27`.

After this, I tried to run `python3 udp_broadcast.py client 192.168.0.255` in the third terminal, but neither of the foregoing two servers received any messages.(**why not?**)

However, if I run `python3 udp_broadcast.py client localhost` or `python3 udp_broadcast.py client 192.168.0.27`, then one of the corresponding server would receive an message.

Finally, I created another server i.e. `python3 udp_broadcast.py server 192.168.0.255`, and this server would receive messages, if running `python3 udp_broadcast.py client 192.168.0.255`, as follows:

```
The client at ('192.168.0.27', 56303) says: 'Broadcast datagram!'
```

Notice that the server pronounced that the client's ip address is 192.168.0.27 rather than 192.168.0.255.(**why it changed?**)

It seems that **the broadcast doesn't work at all**. Very appreciated if anybody could illustrate this!